# Evaluate the limit of $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x} (\sqrt {x} - \sqrt {x -a})$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital, infinity, infinite-groups

The question is in my book and I searched for it and got [this solution](https://socratic.org/questions/solve-lim-x-sqrt-x-sqrt-x-sqrt-x-a). I have reached upto $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x} \frac { a } {(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x−a})}$$ However, I couldn't complete further. I don't understand the fourth and fifth step of that solution of link.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: Ok, wait. I am learning it now

Comment: For instance, ```$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{ x - \sqrt{ x } }$$``` renders as:$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{ x - \sqrt{ x } }$$

Comment: that / is divided by

Comment: You should type the question in the image and show exactly where you're stuck. Do you see how $x-(x-a)=a$ in the numerator? Do you see how they cancel a factor of $\sqrt{x}$ in the denominator?

Comment: To type a fraction, use ```$$\frac{ top }{ bottom }$$``` to render:$$\frac{ top }{ bottom }$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$${\sqrt{x}}({\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x-a}}) = \sqrt{x}({\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x-a}})\frac{({\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x-a}})}{({\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x-a}})}$$ $$= \sqrt{x}\frac{x-(x-a)}{({\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x-a}})} = \frac{a}{\frac{({\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x-a}})}{\sqrt{x}}} = \frac{a}{1 + \sqrt{1-\frac{a}{x}}}.$$

So, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{x}({\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x-a}}) = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a}{1 + \sqrt{1-\frac{a}{x}}} = \frac{a}{2}.$$

The key is to note that
$$\sqrt{x} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}},$$ for $x \neq 0$.

Comment: I understood after you typed $$\frac {a^2} { \frac {( \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x-a} )}  { \sqrt{x} } }$$$

Comment: Yes I didn't understand that key note as the link solution was too direct. Thanks again for answer :)